# Magento 2 - Curl Method coding standard?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, curl

I am calling third party API using below methods:

```
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->_url . 'api/v1/ShipTos');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer $session", "Content-Length: " . strlen($data_string)));

        $out = curl_exec($ch);
```

How to call curl method in Magento 2 with example please?

Comment: Helpful link https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/HTTP/Adapter/Curl.php (didn't help me much though >.<)

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/HTTP/Client/Curl.php Actually this is better, mage docs link to my first link but this seems like the correct one.

Comment: I have same issue. I tried with the below answer. But was not able to set the other curl options as in the question. Can anyone please explain the answer in more detail??

Comment: Hi @Vindhuja what are the other curl option need to can you please explain as separate question. i will help you :)

Comment: I have all the same options as in your question

Comment: i will check and provide ans

Comment: Pls see my code for more reference:
$ch = curl_init();curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);if($method == 'POST'){curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);}curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION ,1);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Accept: application/json',
'Authorization:'.$key
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);$result = curl_exec($ch);curl_close($ch);
return json_decode($result);

Comment: @ Rama Chandran M Do you have any update??

Comment: I am a little busy on a project deadline. i will talk to my college to ans your question on today.

Comment: I got stuck with this. Looking for an answer as early as possible.

Comment: Hi i added seprate question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233153/how-to-write-curl-code-to-magento-2-code my friends will add ans today. i am sorry i am liitle busy on my work . :( i will try do my best :)

Comment: Ok :( Let us hope for an answer soon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 protected $curlClient;
```

in construct add this

```
  public function __construct(     
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl

    ) {
        $this->curlClient = $curl;
    }
```

You can use this like

```
$this->curlClient->post($serviceUrl, []);
//response will contain the output in form of JSON string
$response = $this->curlClient->getBody();
```

For more option you can see this file, `vendor\magento\framework\HTTP\Client\Curl.php`

like

`getBody()`

`addHeader()`

`setCredentials()`

`addCookie()`

`get()` // for get request

`makeRequest()` // for make request

`setOption()` // set curl options

Comment: Thanks Keyur, I have check in my code and come back any issues

Comment: Sure Keyur. 

any idea different between?
Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\Curl
Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl

Comment: @keyur Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain the answer in detail?How to set each curl parameter as in the question(CURLOPT_URL, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST etc). I have searched in this file(vendor\magento\framework\HTTP\Client\Curl.php) and tried the code. But getting error as Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to protected method Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl::curlOption() from context.
Any idea on this??

Comment: @Vindhuja Setting a request method is not possible. 
We need add the functionality in Curl class in next magento release.

Answer (score 0):

The correct method should use the factory pattern. This is an example of the implementation in a helper context.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Middleware\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\CurlFactory;
use Zend_Http_Client;
use Zend_Http_Response;

class CurlHelper extends AbstractHelper
{

    const API_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://www.example.com';

    /**
     * @var CurlFactory
     */
    protected CurlFactory $curlFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param CurlFactory $curlFactory
     * @param Data $helper
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CurlFactory $curlFactory,
        Helper $helper
    ) {
        $this->curlFactory = $curlFactory;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function post()
    {
        $endPoint = self::API_ENDPOINT_URL;
        $requstBody = ['param1'=>0,'param2'=>1];
        $httpAdapter = $this->curlFactory->create();
        $httpAdapter->write(Zend_Http_Client::POST,
                                    $endPoint,
                                    '1.1',
                                    ["Content-Type:application/json","TOKEN:tokenvalue"],
                                    json_encode($requstBody)
        );

        $result = $httpAdapter->read();
        return Zend_Http_Response::extractBody($result);
    }

}
```