# How to write Curl code to Magento 2 code

Tags: magento2, curl, curl-request

This is my curl code. How to write the same in Magento 2

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);

if($method == 'POST') {

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);

}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json', 'Authorization:'.$key ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return json_decode($result);
```

Please help.

Comment: Here's a feature rich example i put together https://github.com/DominicWatts/CacheWarmer/blob/34e96f1ad607e64b0ecbcc06ff440fabaf241adc/Console/Command/Runner.php#L219-L274

Comment: I added the doc referance here for someones future ref - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/gs-curl.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper
) {
    $this->curl = $curl;
    $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
}


$data = []; //add what you need if it is post
$this->curl->addHeader(); //add header
$this->curl->setOption(); //set required options
$this->curl->post(YOUR_URL_HERE, $data); // do post
$this->curl->get(YOUR_URL_HERE); // do get
$body = $this->curl->getBody();
if ($body) {
    $result = $this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode($body);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code is help to use curl in magento2.

```
$client = new \Zend_Http_Client();      
$client->setUri($url);
if($method == 'POST'){
    $client->setParameterPost($data);   
}
$headers = ["Content-Type" => "application/json", "Accept" => "application/json",CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,"Authorization" => $key,"CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT"=>120,"CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER"=>false];
$client->setHeaders($headers );
$response = $client->request($method)->getBody();
```

You will print the response by print_r($response);

Comment: can you provide an example without using new object.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below code for cURL request

```
$apiUrl = "https://magento.com/magento-connect/platinumpartners/list";
$this->getCurlClient->post($apiUrl, []);
$this->getCurlClient->setOptions(
         [
            CURLOPT_REFERER => $this->getReferer()
         ]
       );
$response = json_decode($this->getCurlClient->getBody(), true);
```

for details info, you can go through [Magento Official Doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/gs-curl.html)