# Magento2 Sharing product link for WhatsApp Web with bitly link

Tags: magento2, product, php

Magento2 Share product link for WhatsApp Web with bitly link

how to currentUrl share with bitly link?

```
$objectManagerInstance=\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$url = $objectManagerInstance -> get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');

$currentUrl = $url -> getCurrentUrl(); 

<div class="whatsapp_share <?php echo $size_class; ?>">
  <a href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php echo $text?>%0A%0A<?php echo "",$currentUrl."";?>"><?php echo __('Share');?></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below link for share products in whatsapp  ( for bitly link - can you share url format ? ) .

`https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=www.google.com`

I hope its work for you.

Comment: How can i send my EventObserver log message by whatsapp message? @Anas Mansuri

Comment: try with curl. - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178062/magento-2-curl-method-coding-standard

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that you want to generate a product link, using the bit.ly API, that can easily be shared using WhatsApp?

- use the bit.ly-API to generate a link to your product page:
  https://dev.bitly.com/
- then include a link on your product page pointing to this url: https://wa.me/whatsappphonenumber/?text=YOUR_URL_ENCODED_TEXT

And you should be done.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way...

```
<?php $urlInterface = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
    $_currentUrl = $urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();
?>    
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php echo $_currentUrl?>" data-action="share/whatsapp/share"><img src='WHATSAPP_ICON_IMG_SRC_HERE' /></a>
```